# Create RenderArray of Field

Tags: theming, 8, entities

In my theme_preprocess_taxonomy_term function I am loading a node.
Then want to move its "body field" to the content array of my template.

```
    mytheme_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables){
        $import_content_node_id = 32;
        //load node
        $import_content_node = $node = Node::load($import_content_node_id);
        variables['content']['body'] = $import_content_node->getFields()['body'];
}
```

This does not work because variables['content']['body'] is NOT a render array.

But from where I get the render array?
Or how do I create one from an by script loaded node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method `view()` of the field.

Example, to get the render array of the `body` field as configured in the viewmode `full`:

```
$renderarray = $node->body->view('full');
```